# Java - how to manipulate time for testing?

Tags: java

I'm working with Java and JSP. I have to create something like a promotion which has start date and end date. Within the start date and end date, it will show a form that is corresponding to the promotion; otherwise, it will be just show a normal page. I have done the validation based on the time they open the page. I can manipulate the time in Unit Testing by making the current time to any time I want.

However, the problem is when I want to pass this to client to test. They want to see how it's like on the promotion day? Does the promotion really show on a particular time? Does it really close afterwards? One possible way is to secretly pass current date as HTTP param when trying to access the page. Doing so, client can check how the system behaves on a particular day but it's very dangerous indeed. Anyone who knows this will be able to access the promotion anytime they want. I don't know what the best way to handle this.

What's your suggestion?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't temporarily change the date/time on the server, for demonstration purposes? It sounds like you're still developing it, so I can't imagine this site is actually live.

Comment: I dun have control over the server machine, and even if I can ask for permission, m afraid it may affect the other system. I'm just trying to make my project isolated as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't be putting this functionality onto a live production server, so the "very dangerous" exposure shouldn't happen.

I'd try a "belt and braces" approach:

- Set up a demo server that only has read-only access so can't do any damage
- Tell the client the secret parameter to use
- Have the "client promotion demo" feature switchable on/off from an admin console
- (If you're *really* nervous) limit access to only the client's IP

The client can access the demo box and check everything works perfectly. When they are happy, you deploy to production, but with the "demo mode" disabled, so only the "time-sensitive" way of accessing the promotion will work.

Comment: yes! I like the idea of creating a switchable feature on/off in admin console... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a bad idea basing ANY of your JSP (server-side) code on time being sent from a client.  It would be much better to handle this entirely server side and have some way of configuring the time via which you and your client can do testing.

1) if the client is really concerned (or your application is complex) - it may be that the ONLY way to do such a test reasonably is to change the server time as suggested by Nathan Hoad's comment.  Every other test comes with confidence since it relies on something other than the time ticking over and "triggering" the promotion to start or end.  Also keep in mind the activities that occur during the promotion - do they use the system time to make decisions or store the date/time in a database etc?

2) if #1 isn't a real issue I would have your code that checks the time (for the trigger of the promotion) to call a custom function in your code (eg. `getCustomTime()`).  That method will by default return the system time, but also checks to see if an offset has been configured and use that to offset the actual time.  The offset can be dynamically configured.

Good luck.

Comment: I already reply Nathan Hoad. The thing is I don't have much control over the server machine and m afraid it may affect the other project.
And yes, I like the #2 solution. Gonna put that into consideration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to tweak the time on your server to demo this to the client. Just have a promotion that is expired in the system, one that is currently active and another that is in the future on three different items, and show the customer the effects.

Either that, or create a promotion during your presentation that takes effect one minute in the future, lasts for 2-3 minutes and then expires, then talk through it and click around and show them the effects.